# CentOS 8 freeze on gcloud. How to debug?

Tags: centos, google-compute-engine, freeze, centos8

I run a Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance with CentOS 8 on Google Cloud Platform. The problem is that this instance freezes at random times and the only way to make it work is to stop the instance and start it again. I tried to recreate an instance, this doesn't help.

Here are the screenshots from the GCE monitoring page (freeze from 21:04 Feb 9 to 09:29 Feb 10):

1. [CPU utilization + Network bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZnuL.png)
2. [RAM + Disk space utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HkVC.png)
3. [Network packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGB0y.png)

It's a 2vCPU instance with 2Gb RAM. It runs 2 docker containers (1 for Apache, 1 for FastAPI), it also runs 4 cron jobs every minute. When the machine freezes I can't ssh to it, I can't access any webpage, none of the 4 cron jobs sends any data to a logging server.

Any ideas how I can debug this issue?

Here is the `/var/log/messages` dump in case it's useful:

```
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Stopped target Basic System.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Stopped target Paths.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Stopped target Timers.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: grub-boot-success.timer: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Stopped Mark boot as successful after the user session has run 2 minutes.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Stopped target Sockets.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Reached target Shutdown.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[285938]: Starting Exit the Session...
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopping /run/user/1000 mount wrapper...
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:03:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopped /run/user/1000 mount wrapper.
Feb  9 21:03:39 instance-prod-2 collectd[1307]: write_gcm: can not take infinite value
Feb  9 21:03:39 instance-prod-2 collectd[1307]: write_gcm: wg_typed_value_create_from_value_t_inline failed for swap/percent/value! Continuing.
Feb  9 21:03:39 instance-prod-2 collectd[1307]: write_gcm: can not take infinite value
Feb  9 21:03:39 instance-prod-2 collectd[1307]: write_gcm: wg_typed_value_create_from_value_t_inline failed for swap/percent/value! Continuing.
Feb  9 21:03:39 instance-prod-2 collectd[1307]: write_gcm: can not take infinite value
Feb  9 21:03:39 instance-prod-2 collectd[1307]: write_gcm: wg_typed_value_create_from_value_t_inline failed for swap/percent/value! Continuing.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Started /run/user/1000 mount wrapper.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Started Session 19719 of user user_12345.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Started Session 19720 of user user_12345.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Started Session 19721 of user user_12345.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Started Session 19722 of user user_12345.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Started Mark boot as successful after the user session has run 2 minutes.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Reached target Paths.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Reached target Timers.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Reached target Sockets.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Reached target Basic System.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Reached target Default.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Startup finished in 40ms.
Feb  9 21:04:01 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Feb  9 21:04:06 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: session-19722.scope: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:07 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: session-19720.scope: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:09 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: session-19719.scope: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: session-19721.scope: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Stopped target Default.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Stopped target Basic System.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Stopped target Sockets.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Stopped target Paths.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: dbus.socket: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Stopped target Timers.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: grub-boot-success.timer: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Stopped Mark boot as successful after the user session has run 2 minutes.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Reached target Shutdown.
Feb  9 21:04:10 instance-prod-2 systemd[285996]: Starting Exit the Session...
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopping /run/user/1000 mount wrapper...
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Succeeded.
Feb  9 21:04:11 instance-prod-2 systemd[1]: Stopped /run/user/1000 mount wrapper.

####################### FROZEN  #####################

Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-240.10.1.el8_3.x86_64 root=UUID=0d7450f2-b70b-4208-bfe4-8>
Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
Feb 10 09:29:18 instance-prod-2 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
```

Comment: Can you also post the logs under [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output) with the respective timestamp? Have you also tried increasing the resources like memory or CPU?

Comment: Don't rely solely on the GCP console metrics. Use something like sar to output internal metrics to a network drive that you can access from another machine,

Comment: What is the CentOS version and instance size?
I have also similar issues after Google updated the GCE image to 8.3, and I also have the same symptoms as reported on https://serverfault.com/questions/1050654/dnf-install-on-centos-8-hangs-an-e2-medium-instance.
Switching the instance size to at least n1-standard-1 resolves the issues and those problems immediately goes away.
I suspect this is the Google's problem relating to CentOS8.3 and shrared core instances, because 8.2 images does not have this kind of issues at all.
When frozen, the Prometheus node exporter metrics say its 100% iowait.

Comment: I'm running CentOS 8.3 on e2-small instance. Checked out the serial console logs (thanks @AlexG) and saw exactly the same error as mentioned in the post shared by @laurds. Thanks a lot both! I'll try switching to n1.

Comment: Quick update: instances with non-shared cores are more expensive, so I switched to CentOS 7.9 from CentOS 8.3 keeping the instance size the same (e2-small shared core). The problem has gone, no freezes since then.

Comment: Our research shows that CentOS 8.3 shared core instance is 100% iowait whenever is is frozen.Setting IO scheduler to something that have timeout mechanism might help.